# Il neige « à l'horizontale » ou autrement et est-ce fréquemment employé au Québec ?

Tags: sens, québec, régionalismes, substantivation

> On est au début février, je regarde dehors et **il neige à
>   l'horizontale**. J'ai 28 ans, et on me demande si je veux déménager à
>   Sarasota, en Floride... J'ai dit O.K., c'est beau.
>
> [ François Trahan ds. [Lapresse.ca](https://www.lapresse.ca/affaires/201006/01/01-4285758-francois-trahan-le-stratege-de-wall-street.php), je souligne ]

Peut-on expliquer sommairement le sens de l'emploi avec la substantivation [*à l'horizontale*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9H0933) ; est-ce un emploi courant au Québec et est-ce exclusivement exprimé avec cette substantivation ou [autrement](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9C4447) ?

Comment: Pour autant que je puisse comprendre (je ne suis pas Québécois), cela signifie que le vent est tellement fort que la neige ne tombe pas verticalement mais file horizontalement.

Comment: @Toto Oui, bien je suis Québécois et donc oui. Si je disais _il neige de côté_ comprendrais-tu aussi ? Il n'y a p.-ê. pas grand chose à dire ici, c'est une question où je vérifiais si on avait autre chose que à l'horizontale pcq. spontanément j'avais employé ça dans un commentaire, simple curiosité.

Comment: Il neige à l'horizontale dans le jeu vidéo [_Celeste_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celeste_(video_game)) ([séquence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQjAPWWgdwM)) !

Answer (score 2):

C'est une expression connue, mais pas commune à dire dans la région ou je vis. Cela décrit un symptôme, pas la météo actuelle.

J'explique;

Le synonyme **blizzard** peut-être utilisé.

***Tempête de neige*** peut être utilisé avec l'adjectif ***Bourrasque de vent*** pour dire pour des situations que la neige ce fait transporter à l'horizontale durant une tempête.

Si le vent est soutenu (+40km/h) durant une période de plus ou moins 4 heures et que la visibilité est faible, alors le terme **blizzard** est de mise.

Comme tu peux voir "il neige à l'horizontale" est un terme connu, mais peu descriptif de la situation.

Est-ce arrivé durant un blizzard ? durant des bourrasques de vent dans une tempête ? ou juste avec des bourrasques de vent ?

Ici seul l'auteur connait la réponse, surtout que l'article parle de la crise du verglas du 1998.

> Hiver 1998. François Trahan a beau apprécier le froid et la motoneige,
>   les 60cm de glace qui se sont accumulés sur le toit de sa maison
>   pendant le «Grand Verglas» minent son moral.

Donc j'assume l'auteur a été plus négatif pour décrire la neige.

J'ajoute une belle photo qui montre de la neige tomber presque horizontalement.. Qui vient de cette page; [What Is A Blizzard?](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/what-is-a-blizzard.html)

[image: Neige oblique]

Comment: Tu exagères, moi je dirais que c'est 50 degrés dans l'image :) Mais ok. Par ailleurs le but n'est pas uniquement de parler de phénomènes météo mais aussi simplement de pouvoir décrire ce que l'on voit a contrario d'une autre chose, ici l'horizontale c'est comme le contraire de la verticale, d'une certaine manière. Près de la Place Ville-Marie il peut neiger vers le haut d'autre part. Le contexte c'est que j'ai dit ça et bof, c'est pas une expression c'est comme un constat sur la force du vent et la neige c'est ce qui permet de voir l'air, c'est le support visuel ds. lequel tu lis le vent. Entk

Comment: Le _blizzard_ bien dans une autre question on n'a pas pensé à ça. Je sais pas pourquoi, finalement la neige c'est pas très évocateur pour tout le monde faut croire...

Comment: @enfernette tu a bien raison pour le 50 degrés, lol. Tout de même je l'avais déjà entendue comme expression, mais juste moins fréquemment que d'autres.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne crois que ce soit une expression formelle (contrairement à des termes comme *frasil* ou *embâcle*). C'est parfaitement compréhensible pour quiconque a déjà eu affaire à une grosse tempête de neige, mais ça se range plutôt dans la famille de terme comme *canicule* ou *été des indiens*.

Le premier n'a pas de définition technique (Environnement canada n'émet que des avertissement de *chaleur*), le second n'en a une que parce que les météorologue d'environnement Canda en avait marre de se le faire demander.